# How to add class UIView in addSubview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a code that draws an ellipse, but it's in a separate class that inherits from UIView

```
    class DRAW: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        var path = UIBezierPath()
        path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 36.62, y: 77.54, width: 303.19, height: 495.93))
        UIColor.green.setFill()
        path.stroke()
        path.fill()
        
    }
}
```

If I try to add it via addSubview(), then it is not on the screen, and if I give it the dimensions, then a black crawl for the entire display and only in the middle is the ellipse I need.

```
 view.addSubview(DRAW.init(CGRect(x: 36.62, y: 77.54, width: 303.19, height: 495.93)))
```

How do I display only an ellipse without a black square. I would be grateful for your help

Comment: You seem to have some trouble understanding coordinate systems. `DRAW` and `view` have different coordinate systems. `(x: 36.62, y: 77.54, width: 303.19, height: 495.93)` makes no sense unless it is in a coordinate system. Relative to what point are those coordinates?

Comment: did not quite understand you

Comment: Add what to what as a sub view?

Comment: Where do you want your ellipse to be? I know it's `x: 36.62, y: 77.54`, but that means 36.62 points in the x direction (starting from some location), and 77.54 points in the y direction (starting from some location). What's "some location" here? You haven't specified in your question, and I suspect you haven't thought about this.

Comment: According to these coordinates on the Iphone 11 pro, it should be in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply set the clear background color of your view

```
let yourView = DRAW.init(frame: CGRect(x: 36.62, y: 77.54, width: 303.19, height: 495.93))
yourView.backgroundColor = .clear
self.view.addSubview(yourView)
```